# Can two non-empty sets A and B be unequal yet AB = BA?

Tags: set, programming-languages

If I have two, non-empty, unequal languages A and B and they are both subsets or equal to {0,1}* such that AB=BA then what would be an example that meets the criteria? I've tried:

```
A{0,1} B{0,1}
AB{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)}
BA{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)}

A {0,1,00} B{0,1,00}
AB{(0,0),(0,1),(0,00),(1,0),(1,1),(1,00),(00,0),(00,1),(00,00)}
BA{(0,0),(0,1),(0,00),(1,0),(1,1),(1,00),(00,0),(00,1),(00,00)}

A{00,11} B{1,0}
AB{(00,1),(00,0),(11,1),(11,0)}
BA{(1,00),(1,11),(0,00),(0,11)}
```

But it seems that the only way to have an AB=BA situation is if both sets have the same elements. I think I am missing something here, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Does AB represent language concatenation or Cartesian product?

Comment: Concatenation is represented here, though I have written these wrong the first example should be: AB{00,01,10,11} and BA {00,01,10,11}

Comment: What you've written out here looks more like Cartesian products (pairs of strings) rather than concatenation. For example, {0, 1}{0, 1} = {00, 01, 10, 11} if you're using concatenation, but {(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)} if it's Cartesian products.

Comment: I think I figured it out, say A={1} and B={1,11} then AB=BA={11,111} and the same if the ones are all zeros.